# jquery error when use my ajax setting with url/${} to delete dynamic row

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I put the url with ${id}, i got an error saying the id is not defined

```
  var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": `https://example.restdb.io/rest/example/${id}`,
  "method": "DELETE", // delete based on ID
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-apikey": APIKEY,
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}
```

```js
//[STEP 0]: Make sure our document is A-OK
$(document).ready(function () {
  //what kind of interface we want at the start 
  const APIKEY = "32187321dkasahjsdaaj"; // fake
  getContacts();
  $("#update-contact-container").hide();
  $("#add-update-msg").hide();
  //[STEP 1]: Create our submit form listener = SEND
  $("#contact-submit").on("click", function (e) {
    //prevent default action of the button 
    e.preventDefault();
    //[STEP 2]: ONCE CLICK 
    // let's retrieve form data
    //for now we assume all information is valid
    //you are to do your own data validation
    // get the value from html's elements
    let contactName = $("#contact-name").val();
    let contactID_1 = $("#contact-ID-1").val();
    let contactMentor = $("#contact-mentor").val();
    let contactClass = $("#contact-class").val();
    let contactEmail = $("#contact-email").val();
    let contactPhone = $("#contact-phone").val();
    //[STEP 3]: get form values when user clicks on SEND
    //Adapted from restdb api
    let jsondata = {
      "name": contactName,
      "student_id": contactID_1,
      "mentor": contactMentor,
      "class": contactClass,
      "email": contactEmail,
      "phone": contactPhone
    };
    //[STEP 4]: Create our AJAX settings. Take note of API key
    let settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://example.restdb.io/rest/studentcrud",
      "method": "POST", // we will use post to send info to server to update
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": APIKEY,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": JSON.stringify(jsondata),
      "beforeSend": function () {
        //beforeSend - what to do before request is sent
        //@TODO use loading bar instead
        //disable our button or show loading bar
        $("#contact-submit").prop("disabled", true);
        //clear our form using the form id and triggering it's reset feature
        $("#add-contact-form").trigger("reset");
      }
    }
    //[STEP 5]: Send our ajax request over to the DB and print response of the RESTDB storage to console.
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      $("#contact-submit").prop("disabled", false);
      //@TODO update frontend UI 
      $("#add-update-msg").show().fadeOut(3000); //Contact record successfully added
      //update our table 
      getContacts();
    });
  });//end click 
  //[STEP] 6
  //let's create a function to allow you to retrieve all the information in your contacts
  //by default we only retrieve 10 results
  function getContacts(limit = 10, all = true) {
        //[STEP 7]: Create our AJAX settings
    let settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://example.restdb.io/rest/studentcrud",
      "method": "GET", //[cher] we will use GET to retrieve info
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": APIKEY,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
    }
    //[STEP 8]: Make our AJAX calls
    //Once we get the response, we modify our table content by creating the content internally. We run a loop to continously add on data
    //RESTDb/NoSql always adds in a unique id for each data, we tap on it to have our data and place it into our links 
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            let content = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length && i < limit; i++) {
                content = `${content}<tr id='${response[i]._id}'>
        <td>${response[i].name}</td>
        <td>${response[i].student_id}</td> 
        <td>${response[i].mentor}</td>
        <td>${response[i].class}</td>
        <td>${response[i].email}</td>
        <td>${response[i].phone}</td>
        <td><a href='' class='delete' data-id='${response[i]._id}'>Del</a></td>
        <td><a href='#update-contact-container' class='update' data-id='${response[i]._id}' data-student_id='${response[i].student_id}' data-mentor='${response[i].mentor}' data-class='${response[i].class}' data-phone='${response[i].phone}' data-name='${response[i].name}' data-email='${response[i].email}'>Update</a></td></tr>`;
      }
      //[STEP 9]: Update our HTML content
      //let's dump the content into our table body
      $("#contact-list tbody").html(content);
      $("#total-contacts").html(response.length); // update the no. of contacts
    });
    // this entire is getContact;
  }
  //[STEP 10]: Create our update listener
  //here we tap onto our previous table when we click on update
  //this is a delegation feature of jquery
  //because our content is dynamic in nature, we listen in on the main container which is "#contact-list". For each row we have a class .update to help us
  $("#contact-list").on("click", ".update", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //update our update form values
    //UPDATE FORM
    let contactName = $(this).data("name");
    let contactID_1 = $(this).data("student_id");
    let contactId = $(this).data("id");
    let contactMentor = $(this).data("mentor");
    let contactClass = $(this).data("class");
    let contactEmail = $(this).data("email");
    let contactPhone = $(this).data("phone");
    //[STEP 11]: Load in our data from the selected row and add it to our update contact form 
    $("#update-contact-name").val(contactName);
    $("#update-contact-ID-1").val(contactID_1);
    $("#update-contact-id").val(contactId);
    $("#update-contact-mentor").val(contactMentor);
    $("#update-contact-class").val(contactClass);
    $("#update-contact-email").val(contactEmail);
    $("#update-contact-phone").val(contactPhone);
    $("#update-contact-container").show();
  });//end contact-list listener for update function
  //[STEP 12]: Here we load in our contact form data
  //Update form listener
  $("#update-contact-submit").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //retrieve all my update form values
    let contactName = $("#update-contact-name").val();
    let contactID_1 = $("#update-contact-ID-1").val();
    let contactMentor = $("#update-contact-mentor").val();
    let contactClass = $("#update-contact-class").val();
    let contactEmail = $("#update-contact-email").val();
    let contactPhone = $("#update-contact-phone").val();
    let contactId = $("#update-contact-id").val();
    //[STEP 12a]: We call our update form function which makes an AJAX call to our RESTDB to update the selected information
    updateForm(contactId, contactName, contactID_1, contactMentor, contactClass, contactEmail, contactPhone);
  });//end updatecontactform listener
  //[STEP 13]: function that makes an AJAX call and process it 
  //UPDATE Based on the ID chosen
  function updateForm(id, contactName, contactID_1, contactMentor, contactClass, contactEmail, contactPhone) {
    //@TODO create validation methods for id etc. 
    var jsondata = { "name": contactName, "student_id": contactID_1, "mentor": contactMentor, "class": contactClass, "email": contactEmail, "phone": contactPhone };
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": `https://example-95e6.restdb.io/rest/studentcrud/${id}`,//update based on the ID
      "method": "PUT",
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": APIKEY,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      },
      "processData": false,
      "data": JSON.stringify(jsondata)
    }
    //[STEP 13a]: send our AJAX request and hide the update contact form
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      $("#update-contact-container").fadeOut(5000);
      //update our contacts table
      getContacts();
    });
  }//end updateform function
  //[STEP 14]: Create EVENT LISTENER ON delete 
  $("#contact-list").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hello")
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": `https://example-95e6.restdb.io/rest/studentcrud/${id}`,
      "method": "DELETE", // delete based on ID
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": APIKEY,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }
    }
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log('hi hi');
      //update our table 
      getContacts();
    });
  });
}) // end
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Simple Contact Form System</h1>
  <div id="add-update-msg">
    <!-- will be hide away -->
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Contact record successfully added</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form" id="add-contact">
    <form id="add-contact-form">
      <!-- Input -->
      <!-- Name -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="contact-name">Name</label><input type="text" id="contact-name"
          class="form-control" required></div><!-- Student ID -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="contact-ID-1">Student ID</label><input type="tel" id="contact-ID-1"
          class="form-control" required></div><!-- Mentor -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="contact-mentor">Student Mentor</label><input type="text" id="contact-mentor"
          class="form-control" required></div><!-- Class -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="contact-class">Class</label><input type="text" id="contact-class"
          class="form-control" required></div><!-- Email -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="contact-email">Email</label><input type="email" id="contact-email"
          class="form-control" required><small id="contact-email-help" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share
          your email with anyoneelse.</small></div><!-- Phone -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="contact-phone">Phone Number</label><input type="tel" id="contact-phone"
          class="form-control"></div><input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" id="contact-submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div><!-- end add container -->
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h2>Table information of Contacts (<span id="total-contacts"></span>)</h2>
  <table class="table" id="contact-list">
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Student ID</th>
      <th>Student Mentor</th>
      <th>Student Class</th>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th colspan="2">Actions</th>
    </thead><!-- This will be filled with information later -->
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div><!-- Update -->
<div class="container mt-5" id="update-contact-container">
  <div id="add-update-msg">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Contact record updated sucessfully</div>
  </div>
  <h4>Update Contact</h4>
  <div class="form" id="update-contact">
    <form id="update-contact-form">
      <div class="form-group"><label for="update-contact-name">Name</label><input type="text" id="update-contact-name"
          class="form-control" required></div><!-- Student ID -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="update-contact-ID-1">Student ID</label><input type="tel"
          id="update-contact-ID-1" class="form-control" required></div><!-- Mentor -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="update-contact-mentor">Student Mentor</label><input type="text"
          id="update-contact-mentor" class="form-control" required></div><!-- Class -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="update-contact-class">Class</label><input type="text"
          id="update-contact-class" class="form-control" required></div><!-- Email -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="update-contact-email">Email</label><input type="email"
          id="update-contact-email" class="form-control" required><small id="update-contact-email-help"
          class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyoneelse.</small></div><!-- Phone -->
      <div class="form-group"><label for="update-contact-phone">Phone</label><input type="text"
          id="update-contact-phone" class="form-control"><input type="hidden" id="update-contact-id"></div><input
        type="submit" value="Update Contact Details" class="btn btn-warning" id="update-contact-submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div><!-- DELETE -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.3/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Well, from what you share here we can not possibly ascertain, whether `id` is undefined or not. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: okie no prob:) this is my entire code https://jsfiddle.net/hellojimhellomichael/9wreLh7y/1/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `id`is indeed undefined in the context of the event handler function. We need to get the information from somewhere else.

As the delete action is triggered by a click on a `.delete` element in your `#contact-list` you should get the `id` to be deleted directly from that element. And, indeed, it can be found there:

```
<a href='' class='delete' data-id='${response[i]._id}'>Del</a>
```

The `data-id` holds the `id` as received from the AJAX server earlier. It can be referenced by looking at the `.dataset.id` attribute of the clicked element `e.target`. So, your `.on("click", ".delete", function (e) {...}` should look something like this:

```
$("#contact-list").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm("Do you want to delete this item?")){
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": `https://example-95e6.restdb.io/rest/studentcrud/${e.target.dataset.id}`,
      "method": "DELETE", // delete based on ID
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-apikey": APIKEY,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
      }        
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      //update our table 
      getContacts();
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: hi thank you Carsten! may i ask if it is possible to do a if(confirm) statement, asking user to confirm if they want to delete the entry @Carsten Massmann

Comment: Yes, of course, you can insert an `if()` statement with a `confirm()` before starting the delete action, see my changed answer.